# SCSI Packets from USB

Tags: assembly, usb, disassembly, scsi

So I found this link [Does the first sector (MBR) of a flash drive get executed on insertion into a computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312626/does-the-first-sector-mbr-of-a-flash-drive-get-executed-on-insertion-into-a-co) and was wondering about the specifics of the USB SCSI packets mentioned in the answer.
First, where are they stored in the flash drive? If I do a hex dump of my USB drive, will I be able to view the packets and if so at what memory registers?
Second, how does the computer handle nonstandard packets if every company uses different instruction sets?
Third, how does one go about modifying the packets returned by the drive?

Answer (score 0):

1) firmware can be placed most anywhere in the drive's memory... are you wondering how to access it?
2) afaik there is a universal standard for scsi packets (check wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI#SCSI_command_protocol)
3) the packets are firmware and can only be modified through painstaking disassembly

Comment: About 2) There are also some non-standard commands supported by some manufacturers but by default no OS supports these packages. For a low-level formatting of a hard disk for example you need such special commands which are only supported by special tools provided by the manufacturer.